# Following is my leap year program.It is showing LEAP YEAR for every output

Tags: c, lang, leap-year

My program is showing "it is a leap year" for every output. Please let me know where i am committing an error??

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
int a;
clrscr();
printf("\n Enter the year : ");
scanf("%d",a);

if (a%400 == 0)
printf("\n It is a leap year");

else
if (a%100 == 0)
printf("\n It is not a leap year");

else
if (a%4 == 0)
printf("\n It is a leap year");

else
printf("\n It is not a leap year");


getch();
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `scanf()` function requires you pass the *address* of your variable:

```
scanf("%d",&a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your scanf line `scanf("%d", a);` to `scanf("%d",&a);`. You need to pass the address of a, not its value.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a "&":

```
scanf("%d",&a);
```

so it always returns the first as true as "a" is = 0 no matter what you enter

Comment: It's not 0, it's worse - `a` is *uninitialised* (since it's a local variable and not `static`), so it could contain anything. It's only coincidence that the given code doesn't crash.

Comment: true - i can only assume its equating 0 with uninitialised to avoid a crash. in this case a crash would actually be more useful!!!

Comment: The presence of `<conio.h>` indicates that the OP may be using a 16-bit Turbo C implementation, which of course has no memory protection at all.